# How do I send a json object to a server using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, http, post, server

I'm a beginner at using JS so this may seem like a simple problem to many of you.
I have two servers running on localhost. One on port `5000` and the other on port 8000. I have a folder at `5000/assets/1.json` and am able to retrieve this `json` with an `xmlhttprequest` get call in my `8000`. My problem now lies in the fact that I want to write a json file created in `8000` to `5000/assets`.

I have already tried the xmlhttprequest post method nut this gives me a method not allowed error.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data", "the_text_you_want_to_save");
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:5000/assets/', true);
xhr.send(data);
```

I expect the my data variable to be written into the assets directory of 5000. Do I need a server side script to do so?

Comment: Share your full error

Comment: What are the server processes you have running on those ports?

Comment: Merely POSTing something to a URL won't dump the file there; you need to set up the `/assets/` route in the server, process the POST request and write the file.

Comment: "I expect the my data variable to be written into the assets directory of 5000" — If you made a POST request to `https://www.google.com/` then would you expect Google's homepage to be overwritten with your data?

Comment: `new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` — it is 2019, there is no good reason to be bloating your code with support for Internet Explorer 6 today!

Comment: @Quentin Of course not. I'm just getting into web programming and experimenting with a few basic concepts on things like HTTP,etc. The idea behind this question was not to expect things to work like magic without connecting the dots but to find out what was missing that needed to be done. Again, please go easy on me I'm just starting to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need a server side script to do so?

Unless the server running on port 5000 has some kind of configuration to know that it should respond to that POST request in that way, yes, you'll need to write some code for that server process to do so.

You'll also need to have code or configuration in place that provides the correct [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers on the response, because `http://localhost:5000` and `http://localhost:8000` are different origins, so you won't be able to read the response of the POST due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

Side note: There's no need for that chck on `XMLHttpRequest` unless you need to support truly obsolete versions of IE (like, < IE8).

Comment: Hey T.J, 
Thank you for your reply. I was getting the CORS error when I was trying the GET as well but found an extension on chrome that temporarily disables it.
Yes, I figured that check is not needed. It's in the code because I was trying to replicate something I saw on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to write data onto server without server-side script. Its not possible to do it using plain Ajax.

You can have a backend server running which accepts the json data from the first application and writes it to the disk.